# Running Django test with setup.py test and tox

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, setuptools, tox

I built a Django app and made a package out of it with `setuptools`. Now, I would like to do the following things:

1. I would like to run all tests with `python setup.py test`. But when I issue this command, I get:

   ```
   /usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py:267: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'install_requires'
   warnings.warn(msg)
   usage: setup.py [global_opts] cmd1 [cmd1_opts] [cmd2 [cmd2_opts] ...]
   or: setup.py --help [cmd1 cmd2 ...]
   or: setup.py --help-commands
   or: setup.py cmd --help

   error: invalid command 'test'
   ```
2. I would like to use Tox to run my tests, but I have no idea what should I write in the `command` attribute to run my Django app tests.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in your `setup.py`:

```
test_suite = "test_project.runtests.runtests",
```

And then in your project:

```
#This file mainly exists to allow python setup.py test to work.
import os, sys
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'test_project.settings'
test_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
sys.path.insert(0, test_dir)

from django.test.utils import get_runner
from django.conf import settings

def runtests():
    test_runner = get_runner(settings)
    failures = test_runner([], verbosity=1, interactive=True)
    sys.exit(failures)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    runtests()
```

See [this tutorial by Eric  Holscher.](http://ericholscher.com/blog/2009/jun/29/enable-setuppy-test-your-django-apps/)

Comment: Eric Holscher's tutorial is out of date - see http://gremu.net/blog/2010/enable-setuppy-test-your-django-apps/

Comment: @jwhitlock your link is broken

Comment: Yes, link is broken, but it's not my blog. I've gone back to @Oz123's method for my own projects.

Comment: Here's a link to the archived version of the page @jwhitlock posted: http://web.archive.org/web/20121010073752/http://gremu.net/blog/2010/enable-setuppy-test-your-django-apps/

Comment: See the official Django documentation for similar code: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/testing/advanced/